# Как стандартными средствами проиграть анимацию gif-файла?

Tags: j2me, java

В данном случае `g.drawImage` каждый кадр в сцене отрисовывает только первый кадр gif-анимашки. Как заставить проиграть анимацию полностью?

```
public void Draw(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, g.TOP | g.LEFT);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть такое дело - J2ME не умеет отображать анимированный GIF. Попробуйте [этот](http://www.jappit.com/uploads/src/AnimatedGifEncoder.java) исходник. Заодно отпишитесь работает или нет? Мне самому до крайности любопытно.

Comment: Пробовал его вчера, не работает...
Придеться резать gif на статичные png/* картинки, грузить в вектор и каждый Draw(Graphics g) выдавать новый имейж, но чет мне такой расклад не нравиться...